# loacationmatch with git-recieve-pack not working

Tags: apache-2.2, git

I am trying to set up git-http-backend on my apache2 server.
Right now it is working so far with suexec and a wrapper and all the stuff but without restrictions. I can pull and push.

Now I wanted to include the section to restrcit push permissions:

```
<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Access"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/librepdm.alitecs.de/users
    Require user alexander
</LocationMatch>
```

User file is in place and filled.
This say my apache access_log:

```
93.95.132.202 - - [28/Mar/2012:15:23:18 +0200] "GET /git/test.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 403 357 "-" "git/1.7.8.msysgit.0"
93.95.132.202 - - [28/Mar/2012:15:23:18 +0200] "GET /git/test.git/info/refs HTTP/1.1" 200 331 "-" "git/1.7.8.msysgit.0"
93.95.132.202 - - [28/Mar/2012:15:23:18 +0200] "GET /git/test.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1" 200 341 "-" "git/1.7.8.msysgit.0"
93.95.132.202 - - [28/Mar/2012:15:23:22 +0200] "PROPFIND /git/test.git/ HTTP/1.1" 405 536 "-" "git/1.7.8.msysgit.0"
```

and this my error_log

```
[Wed Mar 28 15:23:18 2012] [error] [client 93.95.132.202] Service not enabled: 'receive-pack'
```

Ok, the hint is good, if I enable http.recievepack in the repo it works BUT if I don't tell the credentials in the url I get again an error AND I don't wan to activate that. So I tried something else. I edited the LocationMatch as follows:

```
<LocationMatch "^/git/.*$">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Access"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/librepdm.alitecs.de/users
    Require user alexander
</LocationMatch>
```

I removed "git-recieve-pack" in the regex. And surprise everything is now protected also pulls BUT if I don't tell my credentials in the URL TortoiseGIT asks me for user and password AND push work without setting http.recievepack to true. The apache log is a little bit different:

```
93.95.132.202 - - [28/Mar/2012:15:46:16 +0200] "GET /git/test.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 691 "-" "git/1.7.8.msysgit.0"
93.95.132.202 - - [28/Mar/2012:15:46:20 +0200] "GET /git/test.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 691 "-" "git/1.7.8.msysgit.0"
93.95.132.202 - alexander [28/Mar/2012:15:46:20 +0200] "GET /git/test.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 466 "-" "git/1.7.8.msysgit.0"
93.95.132.202 - alexander [28/Mar/2012:15:46:21 +0200] "POST /git/test.git/git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 380 "-" "git/1.7.8.msysgit.0"
```

If I comapre that to the first one the first access call is different. In the first part it states 403 - unauthorized but i wasn't asked for credentails and it does not help to pass the in the url. I the second one it states 401 which is good.

So my question is why does the login work if I secure the whole location and not if I only want to secure pushing? The get commands are identical but somehow I am not asked for login. IMHO this is not a problem of git or TortoiseGT or mysysgit but of apache...

Regards,
Alexander

Answer (score 0):

take a look at request

```
/git/test.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
```

It didn't match anymore `<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">` because `service=git-receive-pack` is parameter and not location (URI)

Answer (score 0):

I updated my configuration like this :

```
  <Location /public >

 SetEnv CGIT_CONFIG /srv/git/etc/cgitrc-public
 SetHandler cgi-script
 Options +ExecCGI

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} service=git-receive-pack
 RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTHREQUIRED:yes]

 AuthzLDAPAuthoritative Off
 AuthLDAPURL "ldap://myldap.mycorp.com/dc=mycorp,dc=com?mailNickname"
 AuthLDAPBindDN "ldapaccount"
 AuthLDAPBindPassword password
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "MyCorp LDAP Protected Area"
 require valid-user
```